# In Node js pulling data using http.request from local apache servers fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache, request

I have local Apache '**httpd**' server running on my machine on port 8123.

when I say **'telnet 127.0.0.1 8123'** it works and '**curl 127.0.0.1:8123**' also works. Even http server works from browser. But when I make http request using Node.js it fails.

Code I wrote:-

```
var options = {
    host: '127.0.0.1:8123',
    path: '/test',
    method: 'GET'
};
var callback = function(response) {
// Logs written here.
};
var req = http.request(options, callback);
req.on('error', function(e) { console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message); });
req.end()
```

When I execute it as "node test.js" it throws error :- **"problem with request: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND"**

I'm not understanding my Node.js cannot resolve to my own local server. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `host: 127.0.0.1:8123',` missing a `'` after `host:`, not sure if this is the issue or a copy paste issue, (esp since it shouldn't let you run at all due to it).

Comment: That was an copy paste issue. I will correct it. If that was case, it would have been syntax error.

Comment: What happens if you instead of `request` run: `http.get("127.0.0.1:8123/test", callback);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried separating out the port in your options as illustrated in the documentation? http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback

EDIT: Also it seems using `hostname` instead of `host` for your host's ip/domain is a preferred convention:

```
var options = {
    hostname: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 8123,
    path: '/test',
    method: 'GET'
};
```

Comment: Damn you Node.js. This works! Except the case in "host: '127.0.0.1'," I used hostname. You can update your answer. Thanks man.

Comment: Whoops, sometimes copying and pasting can cause so many issues! hah thanks!

Comment: I just get a message "You are being redirected". No works for me :(